# Open multi files by vim

Tags: git, vim

I know how to open multi modified files in vim with git.

```
vim -O $(git status -uno -s | awk '{print $2}')
```

But when I add this command in .bashrc file

```
export vim_open="vim -O $(git status -uno -s | awk '{print $2}')"
```

It does not work as I expect. I try to echo it but it print only `vim -O`.

EDIT: my bad: `git status -uno -s`

How can I make alias for the command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it print only vim -O.

The whole right-hand side is inside double quotes; that means that the *command substitution* (`$(...)`) is evaluated immediately, while you're defining the variable. If (at that point) you're not in a Git working copy, you will get an error; if there are just no modified files, the result will be empty, and that is persisted in your variable.

#### A proper alias

The `export` command is for *environment variables*; in Bash, there's a separate `alias` command:

```
alias vim_open='vim -O $(git stat -uno -s | awk '\''{print $2}'\'')'
```

Note how I used single quotes to avoid the immediate execution of the embedded command substitution (and then had to escape the other embedded single quotes). Alternatively, I could have kept double quotes and escaped just the `$` characters for command substitution and variable reference:

```
alias vim_open="vim -O \$(git stat -uno -s | awk '{print \$2}')"
```

#### Super powers with a function

Finally, to retain the ability to pass command-line arguments to Vim (these would have to come *before* the file list, but aliases can only append them at the end), you would have to define a shell function instead:

```
vim_open()
{
    #     v--- arguments passed to vim_open are inserted here
    vim "$@" -O $(git stat -uno -s | awk '{print $2}')
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank for your detail answer.

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.

Comment: @GAVD, A couple minor hints: 1) use the full spelling—`git status`; 2) use `--porcelain` instead of `-s`: that's what is supposed to be called by tools; 3) `cut -d ' ' -f 2` is supposedly a bit lighter-weight than `awk` which has a full programming language parser. (1) matters because if your Git installation won't lack such completion, the command will not work.

Comment: @GAVD, printing just the 2nd field may further be simplified to not call an external command by replacing a call to `awk` with `| while read _ fname; do echo "$fname"; done`.

Comment: @GAVD As an addition: in case you want to edit only files with conflicts, you can use `vim "$@" -O $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | awk '{print $2}')` . Not 100% sure if it should be $2 or $1 in this case, as I do not have example output readily available, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest also a similar alias that opens in tab all modified files

```
alias vmod='vim -p `git diff --name-only `'
```

Comment: A less comprehensive answer than the most upvoted one but I'd think it's actually better than using `git status`.